# How can I know which address belongs to which argument of the function in a Crash Dump

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

I am new to crash dump analysis. Here is the output of `bt -f` of my vmcore and I want to see the value of the argument of the function `foo` that it was holding at that time. I have a 64-bit machine and browsing the code I found out that `foo` only accepts one argument. Anyways, is there a way to know which address belongs to which argument.

```
#4 [ffff8807adfaf8c0] foobar at ffffffffa11c7c15 [foo]
   ffff8807adfaf8c8: ffff881033e1d800 ffff8807adfaf8e8 
   ffff8807adfaf8d8: ffff8807adfaf938 ffffffffa11c7ce1
```

This is the register values at the  end

```
RIP: 00007fa64fdfb907  RSP: 00007fff2a187ca0  RFLAGS: 00010246
RAX: 00000000000000a6  RBX: ffffffff8100b072  RCX: 00007fa6506f7390
RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: 00007fa6508fe910
RBP: 00007fa6508fe8f0   R8: 00007fa6508fe930   R9: 0000000000000000
R10: 00007fff2a1884b0  R11: 0000000000000246  R12: 0000000000000000
R13: 0000000000000000  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: 00007fa6508fe990
ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000a6  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `foobar()` was likely passed in a register, so it may not exist at any memory address at all. The type of the argument will dictate whether it was passed in a register, or in memory.

You mentioned in your comment that the prototype of the function is:

```c
static void foobar(struct bar *b)
```

So, the first argument is regular INTEGER type (as defined by the x86_64 ABI; this includes pointers). To find the value of that pointer argument, you'll need to look at the disassembly of your `foo` function from the entry point up until the current instruction (ie, that at `RIP`). The value would have been passed to the function in `%rdi`.

However, the value in `%rdi` may have been overwritten, or modified, between function entry and the instruction that your dump happened. In that case, you may need to do a little detective-work to work backwards and find the argument that was originally passed.

As a general approach, I'd suggest:

- Get a disassembly of the function, from the entry point until the `RIP` shown.
- Look at how `%rdi` is used in that disassembly. Is there anything that modified `%rdi`? Were there any function calls (which may themselves overwrite the `%rdi` value). If not, your argument was `00007fa6508fe910`
- If `%rdi` was modified, see if has been copied to another register, or saved on the stack. If not, see how the caller generated that pointer, by looking at its disassembly.

Comment: The argument is not an integer, it is a struct. What should I do in that case ?

Comment: Was it a struct or a pointer to a struct? Can you include the prototype of foo in your question?

Comment: It is a pointer to the struct 
`static void foobar(struct bar *b)`